# The sun behind the clouds

Tags: idioms

What does "the sun behind the clouds" mean in metaphoric sense.I saw it as a song or program name.I want to use it in literal sense but would like to know what else it can imply.

Comment: Idiomatically we normally talk about ***sunshine after the rain***, or we say ***every cloud has a silver lining*** when we want to use this type of metaphorical reference to "brighter prospects in the future".

Comment: You've also got ***sunshine on a cloudy day*** as per the song by The Temptations, which basically means even though the situation is bad some good is there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing for publication (or producing a video), you probably should keep in mind that ***The Sun Behind the Clouds*** is the name of an existing documentary film. From Wikipedia:

> "*The Sun Behind the Clouds* looks at China's occupation of Tibet from the perspective of the vocally secessionist Tibetan youth, and from that of their spiritual leader, the Dalai Lama, whose reaction to the Chinese presence has been markedly less confrontational."

The phrase can imply the "clouds" we encounter in life sometimes obscure the "truth" of the ever-shining "sun." This metaphor occurs frequently in Vajrayana Buddhism, for instance.

However, there should be no implication with your literal use of the phrase.